# where can I adjust emoji suggestions in iOS10

Tags: iphone, ios, messages, emoji

I want to adjust emoji suggestions in iOS 10, like what car is suggested after typing "car" in a message.
Or how can I add word-emoji links?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try adding more word to the message (i.e. "Red car" instead of "car") or using "sedan" or "formula one" to be more specific?

Comment: if I type car, it shows already a red car, but I thought that there may be a list of all links words-emoji.
In iMessage, you can write a text and before send, you open emoji keyboard, all possible word-emoji replacements will be shown in a yellow/orange font color. by simple touching these, the word is replaced by an emoji :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't. This data is hard-coded in `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreEmoji.framework` in the file `FindReplace.strings`.

However, you can use those files on macOS to look up the keywords that differentiate the various cars. Here they are, I have made bold the unique words that can be used to summon each type of car.

**race car**, racing car, formula 1, formula one

**police**, cop

police, **police car**, cop

(not available)

**taxi**, cab, taxi cab

car, automobile, **hatchback**, vehicle

car, **sedan**

car, **jeep**, **SUV**, automobile

trolley, tram, **street car**